React Native Expo Audio | Send the audio in real time while recording it
I am trying to create a bird recognition application, so when I activate the recognition function, from the UI, I wish to be able to send it to the server in real-time for it to recognize the bird by its songs.
Now I can only send it after I stop the recording.
I haven't been able to find any information online regarding this, or any work-around for it, yet.
Here is the recording function:

  async function startRecording() {
    try {
      const perm = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (perm.status === "granted") {
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
          allowsRecordingIOS: true,
          playsInSilentModeIOS: true
        });
        const recordingInstance = new Audio.Recording();
        await recordingInstance.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY);
        setRecording(recordingInstance);

      recordingInstance.setOnRecordingStatusUpdate((status) => {
        console.log("Base64 recording data:", status);
        console.log("uri: ", recordingInstance.getURI());
      });
        await recordingInstance.startAsync();

      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
    }
  }


Has anyone done this before using expo? Any other suggestions are welcomed!
Thanks!

Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@siteed/expo-audio-stream
It should do what you need, won't work with Expo Go.
I haven't tried it yet as my current focus is on playing streamed audio rather than recording.

You can try websockets, it is used for real time server connection, without the need to call apis. You may find what you are looking for in this link
https://socket.io

I do not know how to read the real-time recoding data of the recording instance, I can only read it after I stop recording, and I am not sure if its possible in React Native.
